# Postgresql запись после редактирования отправляется в конец таблицы

Tags: postgresql

После любого действия с записью в таблице в postgresql, уходит в конец таблицы. Например запись с id 1 после редактирования появляется в конце таблицы после последней записи.

До редактирования -[image: до редактирования]
После редактирвания - (изменился current_sign_in_at) [image: после редактирования]

Comment: У таблицы нет начала и конца. записи лежат так как им вздумается. Если нужен определенный порядок записей в выборке используйте предложение  `order by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почитайте [Физическое хранение базы данных](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/storage-page-layout.html)

Иллюзия, что запись после `UPDATE` пишется в конец - результат тетриса компоновки записей  на странице а также очередности попадания в/из кэша. если хотите сортированные данные на выходе используйте `ORDER BY` как советует Майк